# How to remove action from yoast plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want remove `json-ld` website microdata, and I think I must disable action in the class `WPSEO_JSON_LD`

**Action:**

```
add_action( 'wpseo_json_ld', array( $this, 'website' ), 10 );
```

Changes in my `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'wpseo_json_ld', array( 'WPSEO_JSON_LD', 'website' ), 10 );
```

What I am doing wrong?

**Solution:**

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', 'swp_remove_jsonld_yoast', 10, 2 );

function swp_remove_jsonld_yoast($data, $context){

    if($data['@type'] == 'WebSite'){
        $data = false;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can better use a filter to clear the output by that function I think. There are filters for wpseo_json_ld_output.

```
function remove_json_ld_output( $data ) {
 $data = array();

 return $data;
}

add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'remove_json_ld_output', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe you know how disable that specific function? ("website", output).

Comment: Or second question, how disable exactly "wpseo_json_ld" action?

Comment: If you put an empty return of an array on wpseo_json_ld_output as a filter I think you achieve what your aiming for. The output function of the class will return nothing then. See my updated comment.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding this snippet into my functions.php file

```
add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', '__return_true');
```