# Wordpress Yoast - move strucutured data tag

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed, web-performance, yoast

Yoast plugin is adding a Structured Data script tag near to the top of the page's `<head>` section. I noticed this is being flagged by the Google Page Speed analyser because it's above, and blocking, other stylesheet tags.

Therefore I'd like to move the tag to the bottom of the header.

To start with, I've found there's a way to remove the tag entirely: [How to remove action from yoast plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966885/how-to-remove-action-from-yoast-plugin)

Now I can just hardcode the tag into `header.php` but it would be nicer to re-add the tag that is dynamically generated by the plugin.

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the Google Page Speed report where it is flagging Yoast's `ld+json` script specifically? I'm thinking you might be able to change the priority of the action to push it below the stylesheets, but I want to see that it is actually the linked data that is actually triggering the flag (and not something else).

Comment: For now I elected to just remove the structured text snippet; will try and re-include it at some point in future.